# Dealing with variable(s) left out of the model

Tags: regression

I am trying to determine the impact of services on vocational rehabilitation (VR) customers (because this is a state/federal project I can not send the data). I have about 24,000 cases, the whole population of interest. There are about 50 control variables in the model, all the usual suspects like gender, age, education and so on. Having spent a lot of time looking, there is absolutely no theory to explain what drives income, the dependent variable. VR does not run statistical models and in any case there is limited interest in that field in the impact of services on income. The predictor of interest is a dummy variable. One if you are eligible for a service and get one or more paid service, 0 if you are eligible and get no paid service (of a specific type I am testing a series of services one at a time because who is eligible for services varies - few are eligible for all of them).

The problem I have is that in some cases the impact of service appears to be negative. If you get a paid service you actually earn less than if you do not. I doubt very much that actually getting a service causes you to do less well, at worse it won't help. So either there is some variable left out of the model or (essentially the same) those eligible and those not eligible differ on some dimension other than services or the 50 control variables.

My question is if there is an empirical method to explore what is left out (I assume not) or to control for the excluded variables. I thought of fixed effect regression, but although people close at different times I am not sure if the data would support that (I only know that approach in theory). I just want to know the impact of service delivery, you would think 50 control variables would be enough.